# Why aren't std::chrono::duration instances passed by value in the Standard Library?

Tags: c++11, pass-by-reference, constexpr, pass-by-value

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration):

> The only data stored in a duration is a tick count of type Rep.

However, I've noticed that for example:

[`this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) takes `sleep_duration` by const ref.

[`future::wait_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) likewise takes `duration` by const ref.

etc.

(1) Any particular reason why they are not passed by value instead?

(1a) Does passing by const reference pessimize some possible `constexpr` optimizations?

Comment: Re (1a): Are you asking that as a general guideline or in the context of `thread::sleep_for` and `future::wait_for`? If you are asking in the context of the latter, it makes no sense at all to me. You can't possible optimize a function that is expected to do something for a certain duration.

Comment: @RSahu The thing that got me thinking is, if I call `this_thread::sleep_for(10ms)` the compiler will have to store `10ms` somewhere eg on stack, then take it's address and pass it to `sleep_for` which will then extract 10 from the address and pass it to an underlying sleep function. Whereas, passing `10ms` by value will pass it in a register avoiding needless write/read. In the end it will probably get optimized away by the compiler anyway, so I probably shouldn't worry about.

Comment: Maybe I should ask it as a separate question

Comment: Now that you have explained it, your question makes sense. Although the time taken for all the operations you mentioned will most likely fade in today's hardware compared to the time duration that you are passing to the above functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was a judgement call.  The cost for the common case of the "built-in" durations is small compared to the cost of what the function is going to do (sleep).  And I didn't want to think about the cost of pass-by-value for a custom duration containing a custom `Rep` that might be expensive to copy (e.g. BigNum).